# Div stuck at bottom of parent

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I have the situation in the screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot]

I want the div surrounded in blue to be aligned to the top of the parent div (surrounded in black) as the image (surrounded in red) is. How can I accomplish this?

I know `top -10px` is an option (where 10 is replaced with the exact number) but I need this to work on various screen sizes so finding the exact value that fixes the problem with that method is not an option.

The html for the divs is below:

```
<div class="product">
    <img class="productImg" src="http://placehold.it/300x240">
    <div class="productTxt">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <h3>Price</h3>
        <p>Short Description Short Description Short Description Short Description Short Description Short Description Short Description Short Description Short Description </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.product {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 330px;
    border: 5px solid black;
}

.productImg {
    width: 240px;
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 3px solid red;
}

.productTxt {
    border: 3px solid blue;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vertical-align: top` will align that element to the top.

```css
.product {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 330px;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.productImg {
  width: 240px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.productTxt {
  border: 3px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="product">
  <img class="productImg" src="http://placehold.it/300x240">
  <div class="productTxt">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <h3>Price</h3>
    <p>Short Description Short Description Short Description Short Description Short Description Short Description Short Description Short Description Short Description </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ow, I'm also just typing this :( ... Anyway +1.

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox. And align it like this:

```
.product {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 330px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    display:flex;
    align-items:flex-start;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://codepen.io/ruchiccio/pen/ZemOyV